# Fullpage.js with angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, fullpage.js

i have a problem with implementing fullpage.js on angular-fullstac-generator project. Then problem is I have installed it with bower then i tried to use it like in instructions. For test i added  following code into index.html where are the scripts for controllers and directives and others stuff. 
I posted this on the end AFTER jquery.js.

index.html :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
      //Navigation
      menu: false,
      anchors:['firstSlide', 'secondSlide'],
      navigation: false,
      navigationPosition: 'right',
      navigationTooltips: ['firstSlide', 'secondSlide'],
      slidesNavigation: true,
      slidesNavPosition: 'bottom',

      //Scrolling
      css3: true,
      scrollingSpeed: 700,
      autoScrolling: true,
      scrollBar: false,
      easing: 'easeInQuart',
      easingcss3: 'ease',
      loopBottom: false,
      loopTop: false,
      loopHorizontal: true,
      continuousVertical: false,
      normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2',
      scrollOverflow: false,
      touchSensitivity: 15,
      normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 5,

      //Accessibility
      keyboardScrolling: true,
      animateAnchor: true,
      recordHistory: true,

      //Design
      controlArrows: true,
      verticalCentered: true,
      resize : true,
      sectionsColor : ['#ccc', '#fff'],
      paddingTop: '3em',
      paddingBottom: '10px',
      fixedElements: '#header, .footer',
      responsive: 0,

      //Custom selectors
      sectionSelector: '.section',
      slideSelector: '.slide',

      //events
      onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){},
      afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){},
      afterRender: function(){},
      afterResize: function(){},
      afterSlideLoad: function(anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex){},
      onSlideLeave: function(anchorLink, index, slideIndex, direction){}
    });
  });
</script>
```

and partial view :

```
<div id="fullpage">
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
  <div class="section">Some section</div>
</div>
```

and i get the error :

"  fullPage: Error! Fullpage.js needs to be initialized with a selector. For example: $('#myContainer').fullpage(); "

How to fix that ? thx for anwsers !

Comment: You are probably calling the initialization multiple times if you are using the AJAX tecnique used by Angular.js.
A link to your site would help to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

### Update Nov 2018

Now fullPage.js version 3 is available for Angular with the official component:
https://github.com/alvarotrigo/angular-fullpage

Note it won't require jQuery anymore too!

---

You are probably calling the initialization multiple times if you are using the AJAX tecnique used by Angular.js. A link to your site would help to figure it out.

You might want to make use of the functions [`reBuild`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#rebuild) and [`destroy`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#destroytype) provided by fullPage.js.

Or, otherwise, use normal links in your site rather than AJAX calls.

Don't forget to check [this topics in fullPage.js forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues?q=angular) as well, they might be helpful for you.